# How to start wrapping of a textblock from second row of a Grid?

Tags: xaml, uwp, grid, textblock, word-wrap

I have 2 rows in a grid. In first row I have 5 columns, in every column I have a textblock. In second row I have a divider.
Can I wrap the last textblock so that it should start from the second row of the grid?
Currently this is my xaml code.

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition/>
           <RowDefinition/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="firstName" Visibility="{Binding FullName, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" | " FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#008DFC" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=firstlevel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstLevelParent}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding FirstLevelParent, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" x:Name="firstlevel" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=middleName}" Margin="0,0,-10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondLevelParent}"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding SecondLevelParent, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" x:Name="middleName" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Left"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=lastName}" Margin="0,0,-10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThreeLevelParent}"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="lastName" Visibility="{Binding ThreeLevelParent, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Left"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=fourlevel}" Margin="0,0,-10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding FourLevelParent}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="fourlevel" Visibility="{Binding FourLevelParent, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" Grid.Column="4" TextAlignment="Left"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="deliverypoint" Visibility="Collapsed">
                 <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeliveryPoint}" x:Name="deliverypointname" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </Grid>
            <!--<TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,-6,0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=lastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>-->
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
```

Thanks in advance.[image: Auto suggest last text block wrapping.]

Comment: I could not understand what you're doing. Could you draw a diagram to describe the effect you want?

Comment: Added current implantation screenshot. Can the wrapping of the last text block start from the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested that you do not use 'Grid.ColumnDefinition' to layout your TextBlock. Instead, you could use [WrapPanel XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) to wrap these TextBlock. Once the max width or height is reached the control automatically create row or column based on the orientation.

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalSpacing="10">
            <TextBlock Text="FullName"  x:Name="firstName"  TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" | " FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#008DFC"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="FirstLevelParent"  x:Name="firstlevel"  TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Text="SecondLevelParent"  x:Name="middleName" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Text="ThreeLevelParent" x:Name="lastName" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="#008DFC" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Text="FourLevelParentFourLevelParentFourLevelParentFourLevelParentFourLevelParentFourLevelParentFourLevelParent" x:Name="fourlevel" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </controls:WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Xavier Xie. This was a bug since I started the app development and thought I would resolve it in the end, I think it is that time now. Thanks again.